# URL rewriting without htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

My current url is

http://demomyurl/index.php/product/detail/7/XYZ

I want it is like

http://demomyurl/index.php/product/detail/XYZ

without .htaccess in codeigniter

Comment: what you are asking..can you check your question once.

Comment: you can user routes.php for rewriting in Codeignter

Answer (score 1):

You would use Routes to do this, I am assuming the "7" is the product id and the "XYZ" is the product name...

```
$route['product/detail/(:any)'] = 'product/get_by_name/$1';
```

This will go to a method named "get_by_name" within your product controller. This would mean the product name (like the product id) would also have to be unique.

You can read up on Routes in the user guide.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Hope this helps.